# regex numbers outside of range

Tags: regex, pcre

i am looking for regex expression for numbers outside of particular range.

NOT Accepted numbers are `v10,v11,v12,v13,v14,v15`. My regex for this is `v(1[0-5])` but 
I <s>dont</s> want numbers anything other than those 6 numbers.

```
v1 - accepted. Need regex for this
v5 - accepted. Need regex for this
v100 - accepted. Need regex for this
v51 - accepted. Need regex for this
v10...v15 - not accepted. I already have a regex for this.
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Use anchors or boundaries to make the matching stricter.</s>

```
\bv(1[0-5])\b
```

or

```
^v(1[0-5])$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TPkTom/1/

Anchors/boundaries will require an exact match. Without those only part of the expression must match.

Per the update a negative lookahead would work:

```
v(?!1[0-5]\b)\d+
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/TPkTom/4/

or you could use PCRE verbs:

```
\bv1[0-5]\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|v\d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/TPkTom/3/

Comment: i have actually clarified by editing the question. can you please take a look

Comment: @yregex2017 Oh, so kind of a mixing. Answer updated.

Comment: you are a genius!  Thanks a lot.